# stop a Count DownTimer if a condition in its onTick occurs then call its onFinish method

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer, countdowntimer

well i have a thread running before my count down timer is started then when a variable inside that thread changes its value that will trigger a condition inside `onTick()` method which will call `onFinish()` and execute the required operation, the problem is that after the condition applay on `onTick()` method the count down timer will keep on running and and execute `onFinish()` method more than once, I've tried to use custom count down timer that allow me to cancel the timer inside the `onTick()` but it didn't work and the app just hang and i also tried to add a flag to execute the code once if the `onTick()` already executed the `onFinish()` but it didn't work it return false value and some times it get back to the parent timer PS. i do have two count down timers and the one that i want to applay the above process on; is the second one which exists into `onFinish()` of the first on well, here is the code:

```
cdt=    new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {//CountDownTimer(edittext1.getText()+edittext2.getText()) also parse it to long

                             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                              //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                             }

                             public void onFinish() {

                                 if(connectionAccepted!=null){
                                     new CountDownTimer(15000,1000) {//CountDownTimer(edittext1.getText()+edittext2.getText()) also parse it to long

                                         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {if(assignMsg!=null){
onFinish();
//Stop the timer here so it doesn't call onFinish more than once
}

                                          //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                                         }

                                         public void onFinish() {
                                             chatClient.interrupt();
                                             try {
                                                serverSocket.close();
                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                             socket.close();
                                             progressDialog.dismiss();
                                             if(assignMsg!=null){
                                                 new AlertDialog.Builder(TicketDetails.this)
                                                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                                                    .setTitle("Result")
                                                    .setMessage("Task has been: "+assignMsg)
                                                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)

                                                .show(); 
                                             }else{
                                                 chatClient.interrupt();
                                                 try {
                                                    serverSocket.close();
                                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                                 socket.close();
                                                 new AlertDialog.Builder(TicketDetails.this)
                                                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                                                    .setTitle("Result")
                                                    .setMessage("User didn't respond!")
                                                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)

                                                .show(); 
                                             }
                                         }
                                        }
                                        .start();
                                 }else{
                                     chatClient.interrupt();
                                     try {
                                        serverSocket.close();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                     socket.close();
                                     progressDialog.dismiss();
                                     new AlertDialog.Builder(TicketDetails.this)
                                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                                        .setTitle("Result")
                                        .setMessage("Network Error!")
                                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)

                                    .show(); 
                                 }
                             }
                            }
                            .start();


            }});
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: your requirement is to stop the coutDownTimer when value changes?????

Comment: as you can see: public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {if(assignMsg!=null){
onFinish();
//Stop the timer here so it doesn't call onFinish more than once
}
i want to stop the timer after assignMsg change its value and then execute onFinish(); but execute it once only, now with this code it calls onFinish(); multiple times till the count down timer finish its time

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `onFinish()` can't be called inside `onTick()`, rather, this is what you can do

```
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
    //your code here
    new Handler().post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            onFinish();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `cancel()` method when you want to cancel the timer.

```
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
    if(condition) {
        cancel();
        onFinish();
     }
 }
```